# Perl: Compare Values of 2 Files & Print Values of 2nd File which fall in a particular range of values from 1st file

Tags: perl, hash, bioinformatics

I have run into a little glitch. I have 2 files which look like this:

**File1**

```
chr10   179423  181499  181423  2076    +   NM_001202464    ZMYND11
chr10   693887  696118  695887  2231    +   NR_027151   C10orf108
chr10   694016  696382  696016  2366    +   NR_027152   C10orf108
chr10   1032348 1034467 1034348 2119    +   NM_012341   GTPBP4
chr10   1203707 1205930 1205707 2223    +   NR_015376   LINC00200
```

**File2**

```
chr10   176225
chr10   180990
chr10   181315
chr10   181529
chr10   181695
chr10   182183
chr10   686673
chr10   686699
chr10   688273
chr10   695323
chr10   698323
chr10   722737
chr10   906075
chr10   908409
chr10   928052
chr10   950429
chr10   989722
chr10   1006348
chr10   1010731
chr10   1020229
chr10   1034526
chr10   1064089
chr10   1103000
chr10   1103198
chr10   1103267
chr10   1114980
chr10   1135327
chr10   1150625
chr10   1193412
chr10   1193677
chr10   1199817
chr10   1212181
chr10   1212310
chr10   1216875
chr10   1218919
chr10   1226134
chr10   1226254
```

**What is Required**

Going row-wise, for every `4th element` from `File1` print out the values from `File2` which are `>= 2nd element from file1 & <= (4th element from file1+2000)`

So for example, in `File1`, 4th element in `row1` is *181423*. From `File2`, the values which are `>= 2nd element from file1` *(179423)* and `<= 4th element from file1+2000`*(183423)* are 18090,181315,181529,181695,182183.

In case no values are found, `NA` should be printed.

**Desired Output**

A tab delimited file which looks like this:

```
chr10   179423  181423  183423  NM_001202464    ZMYND11     180990
                                                            181315
                                                            181529
                                                            181695
                                                            182183
chr10   693887  695887  697887  NR_027151   C10orf108       695323
chr10   694016  696016  698016  NR_027152   C10orf108       695323
chr10   1032348 1034348 1036348 NM_012341   GTPBP4          1034526
chr10   1203707 1205707 1207707 NR_015376   LINC00200       NA
```

**My Code**

I am absolutely clueless as to how to go about it. Initially, I was told that I simply need to find those values from `file2` which are between the `2nd` and `4th` element of `file1` . For that , I had written the following code using hashes, which although working, was not doing the complete job. (The `&&` portion in the `if` loop isn't doing what I thought it should, so all the greater values are being printed)

Now this code is complete useless :/ I am at my wits end because I don't know if within 3 months into Perl programming, I am supposed to be able to write crafty programs.

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;

#Assign filenames
my $file1 = 'file1.txt' || die $!; #File with TSS coordinates
my $file2 = 'file2.txt' || die $!; #File with G4 coordinates

#Open files
open my $fh1, '<' , $file1 || die $!;
open my $fh2, '<' , $file2 || die $!;

#Open output
open OUT, ">G4_coordinates_promoters$file1.out" || die $!;

#Read files
while (<$fh1>) {
    chomp;
    my %data1; #Hash for TSS
    my ($key1, $val1) = (split) [1,3];
    $data1{$key1} = $val1;
    while (<$fh2>) {
        chomp ;
        my %data2; #Hash for G4 coordinates
        my ($key2, $val2) = (split) [1,2];
        $data2{$key2} = $val2;

        #Compare hashes
        if ( ($key2 > $key1) && 
             ($key2 << $data1{$key1})){ #Here the code after && is NOT working
            say OUT $key2
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for going though my issue. I'd be grateful if some straightforward way could be found for approaching this problem.

Comment: Loving the `#Exit` comment on `exit`!

Comment: @Borodin Thank you sir! I try to label my code parts so that I know what each region is doing, even though some may be very obvious.

Comment: @Neal You know that your `die` statements will never happen, right? Because `"string"` is always true, the `||` operator has higher precedence than comma operator, and also short circuits.

Comment: I suspect you did not intend to use the left shift operator `<<` in `$key2 << $data1{$key1}`.

Comment: @TLP Thank you for the comments sir! I am using `||` in place of `or`. Sometimes, if I mistakenly write the wrong input file name, then the `die` statement does help sir. And yes, you are right sir, the left shift operator should not have been written.

Comment: @Neal: TLP is telling you that `||` doesn't work in place of `or` in this code. Your program is broken, and none of the `die` statements will never happen so they cannot be helping.

Comment: @Neal No, the die statement is never used, unless you change your code to insert `0` or the empty string as your file names. Your `open` statement with parentheses inserted to emphasize precedence looks like this: `open my $fh1, '<' , ($file1 || die $!)`.

Comment: @Borodin Okay sir, so henceforth I will write it simply as `open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die $!`. I was under the mistaken assumption that `or` could be written as `||` also.

Comment: @TLP Thank you for pointing this out sir. I would not have known about this.

Comment: @Neal It is a difficult bug to detect. `perldoc perlop` has the precedence table. You can see that `||` is higher than comma `,`, but `or` is lower.

Comment: @TLP I consider myself fortunate to have found a place like this where there are veterans like you to guide novices like me. In the absence of real world teachers, this is where I can really learn good stuff!

Comment: @Neal I feel the same way. I have learned many new things during my time here at stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program seems to do what you need.

The output is written in tab-separated format - the same as your input data - so the continuation lines have the correct number of tabs but aren't physicallly aligned with the initial line. If you want something different then please say so.

All of the values in `file2` are pulled into array `@file2` and processed from there. The code assumed that the values are already sorted.

```
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my @fields = split /\t/;

  my $min = $fields[1];
  my $max = $fields[3] + 2000;

  my @values;
  for my $val (@file2) {
    last if $val > $max;
    push @values, $val if $val >= $min;
  }
  push @values, 'NA' unless @values;

  for my $val (@values) {
    print join("\t", @fields, $val), "\n";
    $_ = '' for @fields;
  }
}
```

**output**

```
chr10 179423  181499  181423  2076  + NM_001202464  ZMYND11 180990
                181315
                181529
                181695
                182183
chr10 693887  696118  695887  2231  + NR_027151 C10orf108 695323
chr10 694016  696382  696016  2366  + NR_027152 C10orf108 695323
chr10 1032348 1034467 1034348 2119  + NM_012341 GTPBP4  1034526
chr10 1203707 1205930 1205707 2223  + NR_015376 LINC00200 NA
```

Comment: Hello sir! Thank you again for a straightforward method. Just one more modification is needed. I need to print `NA` for those entries where no value is found. How do I do that?

Comment: And if I understand this line of code correctly, `$_ = '' for @fields;`, the `''` puts a blank line whenever multiple values are found?

Comment: I have modified my answer for your new requirement. `$_ = '' for @fields` sets all the fields to an empty string so that the values aren't printed on more than one line (but the correct number of tabs *are* output).

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I truly wish that someday I may be able to write programs as well as you do! I really like your simple, straightforward style. I wish I had you as my teacher :)